# What do these Go build flags mean? netgo -extldflags "-lm -lstdc++ -static"'

Tags: go, command-line, compilation

I'm currently taking a microservice online course where I deploy small go apps to docker containers. The long and ugly command line to build the binaries is this one:

```
go build --tags netgo --ldflags '-extldflags "-lm -lstdc++ -static"'
```

till now I just used `go install` to compile my go app.

Can anyone explain this command to me?

Comment: Static linking of external libraries/dependencies into the compiled binary.

Comment: to make it portable? could you explain the command line arguments to me?

Comment: Portable, yes. 'netgo' is a Go build tag for using a pure Go network lib instead of the host's. The rest invokes an external linker. This is a nice tutorial explaining the basics http://blog.hashbangbash.com/2014/04/linking-golang-statically/

Comment: @Nadh is exactly correct (and should make an answer to get credit). I've j own about these options for a while; but, I did not concive of a combined usage until I just saw your example in the question. Wow, that is a perfect use case - minimal docker image `from scratch`.  I think I'm going to update all of my docker images to these tags and build options. awesome.

Comment: what's the online course?

Comment: thanks guys :) @eduncan911 free udacity online course about scalable microservices : https://www.udacity.com/course/scalable-microservices-with-kubernetes--ud615 very recommendable!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

--tags [netgo is used to use go lang network stack](https://golang.org/src/net/net.go)

--ldflags [sets the flags that are passed to 'go tool link'](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies)

The value of the args to ldflags is explained in the [go tool link help](https://golang.org/cmd/link/)

```
-extldflags flags
    Set space-separated flags to pass to the external linker.
```

In this case the external linker is 'ld' 
so you can read [the man page for it](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) 
Meaning of each of the arguments is:

```
-lm enables linking of the standard math library
-lstdc++ enables linking of the standard c++ library
-static means do not link against shared libraries
```